# When invoking AutoCAD through interop, how to to find current installed AutoCAD program ID

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I am using interop and within a console application launching CAD as per the following example. How can I find the programID of AutoCAD which is installed on my local machine.

For example in the below article it uses

```
const string progID = "AutoCAD.Application.17.1";
```

https://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/12/launching-autoc.html

Answer (score 0):

Try just using "AutoCAD.Application" with no specific reference. Works for me.

Your issue is going to be the reference to the proper version of AutoCAD though. I get around this by using late binding.

[Pretty good information on Late Binding](https://forums.augi.com/showthread.php?103628-Late-Binding-of-AutoCAD-Type-Library)

Not really sure that this is kept up to date -->
[AutoCAD Version List](https://www.cadforum.cz/cadforum_en/products.asp)